# Prevent direct access to file on webserver, but make it accessable from a webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my homepage I use this code:

```
 <audio><source src="/files/audio/x.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

I want my homepage to display the audioplayer, but when someone enters the url (https://www.website.com/files/audio/x.mp3) the user should be blocked from opening the file.

I found several "solutions" using .htaccess and a seperate php-file for checking, but none of them worked for me (or I did something wrong...)

Could someone help me with this?

I tried to add a redirect through .htaccess. The file was blocked from viewing from the direct url, but also didn't show up in the audioplayer on the homepage...

Comment: There is no difference, in practice, between a URL accessed via a link in a page, and a user typing it into the address bar. Both generate a HTTP request to that URL, and the server cannot tell which one originated in which way. Are you trying to prevent people from downloading your files? Well actually if they heard the audio in their browser via the `<audio` tag, then the data was already transmitted to their computer (otherwise it couldn't have come out of their speakers), so they already possess it, if they know how to save it.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You won’t be able to completely block “direct downloads” and prevent anyone from downloading the file to their computer. At best you can do some light header checks and deter the most naïve direct access, if at all. But anyone who knows even slightly what they’re doing will be able to download the file anyway.

Comment: Unless you're a megacorp who can pay $$$ for DRM technology and complicated streaming architectures, then realistically you either don't put your content online, or at  least you put it behind a paywall. And you accept that it will be stolen a certain % of times, and build that into your costs. And you have some legal blurb (written by a lawyer) and proper copyright, so you have some recourse against large-scale thieves. It's arguably not actually a technology issue. The web is open, that's the way it was designed.

Comment: (And even then, those big companies can't 100% stop people from copying the content, they can just make it more difficult)

Comment: What you can see and hear can be recorded. There's no protection. You could implement some token mechanism to make it harder to simply download for the average user.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**NOTE**

This is extremally light on security .. Anyone who wants the file can just spoof the URL in the headers, and easily access your file..  This is just a way to keep honest people honest.  It's really not a thorough security solution for "protecting" your files.  If you REALLY want to do that, you should have some sort of authentication, where users log in to view your content.

That said...

The easy way to do it is just through `.htaccess`.  Create yourself a 403 (Not Authorized) Page .. Here we'll call it `403.html` in your root directory.  Then put this `htaccess` in your `audio` directory.  A also added a small block that will allow you to filter by file type if so desired.

This will check for both `www` and `non-www` versions of your domain.

It is important to note that the `Deny` comes first before the `Allow`.  This allows us to Deny all and then allow based on the file check and referrer check.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
SetEnv deny=0
SetEnvIf Referer "^https://yourdomain\.com/" deny=1
SetEnvIf Referer "^https://www\.yourdomain\.com/" deny=1


<FilesMatch "\.(mp3|mp4|mpg|jpg|gif)$">
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from env=deny
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Also note that this might break the actual audio player if users are suppressing their referer, as some browser extensions will.

Comment: @deceze That's a good point.   It could also break the audio player if behind a proxy or internal network using a firewall such as Sophos